# multidimensional arrays to draw a picture

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am doing multidimensional array problems and it got a lot confusing..

basically the instruction is to write a method

```
public static boolean[][] cross(int l, int h)
```

which returns an image of size l, h containing two centered lines, one horizontal, one vertical, forming a cross.

Then I am meant to design a main method displaying the content of that image..

but coming from a java newbie, I can't understand why there is a boolean at all and how to even return a picture...

PS. we do have a uni specific library that allows us to draw a point like

```
awef.drawPoint(i,j);
```

draws a point.

Any sort or form of help will be greatly appreciated..

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In your case, a boolean is a point (a pixel for instance). If the boolean is true, the point is black (filled), else the point is white (empty). Therefore, the first dimension of your array is the x coordinate of the points, and the second dimension is the y coordinate.

Since you have a method to draw a point at a specific coordinate, you will call this method for each boolean that is true.

Something like:

```
public void drawImage(boolean[][] points, int l, int h) {
    for (int x=0; x<l; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y<h; y++) {
            if (points[x][y] == true) awef.drawPoint(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```